# Not able to understand ColorDrawable in Android

Tags: android, colors, drawable

I have been learning Android for a few days (or at least trying), but I can get around Drawables, ColorDrawables and so on. I tried using a simple ColorDrawable that fills the whole screen with a red color...

```
<color xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
android:color="#FFFF0000"
</color>
```

But I can't get the thing about Canvas, Paint and ColorDrawables objects. I Have searched in books, google, the Android Docs and StackOverflow, but I can't get a straight answer on how things should be called in order to show on screen drawables (ColorDrawables, ShapeDrawables, images... and so on).

I know my question might be too general, but can someone help me, or at least point me to a book or webpage that has more detailed and deeper information about this stuff?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solid color, in particular, you normally wouldn't bother with a ColorDrawable in code because most standard classes give you a `setBackgroundColor(int)`; and in XML the `android:background attribute` lets you specify a color.

Let's assume you have more complicated things in mind. In general, you'll use `Drawables` more in XML layouts than in code. In code, you have the choice of letting a `Drawable` draw itself or subclassing `View` and overriding `View.onDraw(Canvas)` and painting what you want. For example, you could code a new `ColorDrawable` and then let it paint itself via `ColorDrawable.draw(Canvas)`, but you could do the same thing through `Canvas.drawColor(int)`.

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps

[Drawable Manual](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html)

Comment: sadly no, I already found that but it just describes the xml files, but what I am talking is more about an explanation on how Android draws stuff, but thanks.